# How to filter to top n for specified column?

Tags: r, rank

I am attempting to find the top n cyl by measure of AVGMPG for each carb, and then ommit everything else in the data frame. My actual problem involves identifying the top sales staff by market by measure of close rate. Hopefully that will make it more clear what I am attempting to do.  Is there a way to easily do this?

```
> mtcars.1 <- mtcars %>%
+   group_by(carb,cyl) %>%
+   summarise(AVGMPG = mean(mpg))
> mtcars.1
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   carb [?]
   carb   cyl AVGMPG
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     4   27.6
2     1     6   19.8
3     2     4   25.9
4     2     8   17.2
5     3     8   16.3
6     4     6   19.8
7     4     8   13.2
8     6     6   19.7
9     8     8   15
```

Comment: did you check the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 3
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(carb) %>% 
   mutate(AVGMPG = mean(mpg)) %>%  
   group_by(cyl) %>%     
   top_n(n, AVGMPG) %>%
   select(carb, cyl, AVGMPG)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with `data.table`

```
data(mtcars)          

setDT(mtcars)

mtcars[,AVGMPG := mean(mpg), keyby = list(carb, cyl)] 
mtcars[order(-AVGMPG),head(.SD, n = 3), by = carb][,.(carb, cyl, AVGMPG)]

    carb cyl AVGMPG
 1:    1   4  27.58
 2:    1   4  27.58
 3:    1   4  27.58
 4:    2   4  25.90
 5:    2   4  25.90
 6:    2   4  25.90
 7:    4   6  19.75
 8:    4   6  19.75
 9:    4   6  19.75
10:    6   6  19.70
11:    3   8  16.30
12:    3   8  16.30
13:    3   8  16.30
14:    8   8  15.00
```

This calculates the mean of `mpg` for `carb`and `cyl`,  order the `carb`-groups by `AVGMPG` and pick the top `3` elements, then it discards all other columns.